# i am using spinner there is 50 item in the spinner i want at a time only 10 item display rest scroll but the spinner take whole the screen

Tags: android, spinner

**xml of spinner**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_length"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textview_sky_bolor"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="length"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_length"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA Code**

```
private String[]  spinnerItemsAmp={"5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","45","46","47","48","49","50"};

binding.spLength.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.spinner_length_layout,spinnerItemsAmp));
binding.spLength.setSelection(0,false);
binding.spLength.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
    mLength=binding.spLength.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}
```

Here spinner open but it take whole the screen i want to decrease the height of spinner means it display in half screen

Answer (score 0):

try using this in

```
your_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple‌​_spinner_dropdown_it‌​em);
```

Comment: but i am using   binding.spLength.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.spinner_length_layout,spinnerItemsAmp));  i am not using custom adapter

Comment: used but not working plz give another solution

Comment: try removing maxLines

Answer (score 0):

if that doesn't work try

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
your_array, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner_name.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: any other solution for this